# В regexp русские символы считает неправильно

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Заметил что если написать такую регулярку

```
/(\S{1,24}+)/
```

То если вводить русские символы regexp считает их неправильно, почему-то один русский символ равен двум.

А вот если английские то все нормально.

В чем дело? Как исправить?

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали, язык и ОС. Не все же могут залезть в чужую голову...

В любом случае смотрите в сторону `setlocale` (или аналога в Вашей системе).

Comment: Язык php, а ОС то зачем?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 русская буква = 2 байта в кодировке utf-8.
Используйте функции для работы с многобайтными строками.
Если работаете с PHP:
**[Что такое многобайтные строки?](http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/intro.mbstring.php)**
**[Как правильно посчитать длину многобайтной строки?](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strlen.php)**

**update:**
Используйте модификатор **u**

```
/(\S{1,24}+)/u
```

**[Рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/giinyx)**
**[Ваш исправленный пример](http://ideone.com/GyZWE6)**

Comment: Если вы хотите мне рассказать как считать количество..то это я знаю.

Или Вы знаете как эту функцию сюда засунуть?!

     /(\S{1,24}+)/

Comment: Где вы используете данную регулярку? В PHP? В MySQL?

Comment: PHP

     $text = preg_replace("/(\S{1,24}+)/", '->\\1', $text);

Comment: Можете собрать рабочий пример на http://ideone.com/ со строкой, в которой пытаетесь заменить текст? Тогда постараюсь вам помочь.

Comment: http://ideone.com/8K2jaw

В одних дужках должно быть 24 русских символа, но их 12.

Думаю смысл кода там понятен.

Comment: @M11, я обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Модификатор u следует использовать только если в строке будут русские символы?

Comment: При включении этого модификатора шаблоны обрабатываются как UTF-8 строки. Соответственно, используйте его всегда, когда работаете с UTF-8 строками.  
**[Документация][1]**
[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php